# cómo eliminar la extensión de archivos de la carpeta de assets [Android]

Tags: android

Actualmente tengo un array de los pdf que están en la carpeta assets de android, pero cuando se listan en en el Listview se ven con la extensión .pdf, como puedo eliminar la extensión de los archivos?

```
    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);

    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

    try {

        String[] filelist = assetManager.list("Pdfs");


        if (filelist == null) {
            // dir does not exist or is not a directory
        } else {

            for (int i=0; i<filelist.length; i++) {

                arrayList.add(filelist[i]);
                
            }

            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);

            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                String data = (String)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();




    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar un simple reemplazo de caracteres,

```
s = s.replace(".pdf","")
```

Pero la forma correcta es buscar la última incidencia del caracter "." (usando `lastIndexOf()` ), ya que pudiera existir nombres de archivos con este caracter antes de la extensión

```
    if(s.contains(".")){
       s = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf('.'));
     }
      arrayList.add(s.replace(".pdf",""));
```

Ejemplo:

```
 List arrayList = new ArrayList();
  
  String[] filelist = {"one.pdf", "two.pdf", "three.pdf", "filecuatro","file.cinco.pdf"};
  
 for (String s : filelist) {
     if(s.contains(".")){
      s = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf('.'));
     }
      arrayList.add(s);
 }

  System.out.println(arrayList);
```

Salida, son extensión .pdf:

```
[one, two, three, filecuatro, file.cinco]
```

Answer (score 0):

Econtre la solucion, si alguien le pasa , de esta manera se puede hacer:

```
String[] filelist = assetManager.list("Pdfs");

        for (String s : filelist) {

          arrayList.add(s.replace("_"," ").replace(".pdf",""));
     }
```